# Angular web app: Splash screen is not rendered and browser is busy fetching the js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have angular application in which I want to show the user a splash (loading text) immediately while the browser fetches all the resources like js files and images.

I have included only css files in the `head` section. The first element in the `body` is the `div` that has the text `Loading` in it.

All the `script` tags are at the end of the `body` (just before the closing tag).

The issue is, theoretically the browser should render the loading text as the first thing, but what happens is that i just see a white screen until all my js files are fetched (even if i have only one after concatenation, the browser still fetches them first and then my loader comes after a long white screen).

Here is what I am doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="link to first css file" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="link to second css file" />


</head>
<body ng-app="my-app" class="{{$state.current.name}}">
  <div ng-hide="loaded()">
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-wrapper" ng-cloak>
    <!-- all other angular app content is wrapped into this section -->
  </div>

  <script src="first script"></script>
  <script src="second script"></script>
  <script src="third script"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Unable to figure out why the Loading msg is not shown and browser starts fetching the js files. I am using angular 1.2.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason for why my loading message was not being displayed. It turned out to be a silly CSS issue after all. :)

The `body's` height was 0 px as there was no content and my `div` was positioned absolute. (so it did not add to the body's height)

For me, making my `div` to position `fixed` solved the case.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-hide` should be listening to a property on `$scope`, not calling a function.

You need your code to look something like:

```
$scope.loaded = false

myLoadingFunctions() {
  // ... do loading stuff
  $scope.loaded = true;
}
```

And then your loading div is:

```
<div ng-hide="loaded">
  <h2>Loading...</h2>
</div>
```

If you look at the console, it's likely that you're either interrupting your JS or calling a non-existent method and causing an error, or the `loaded()` call is simply evaluating to `null` and therefore hiding the div.

Comment: I removed ng-hide from the div, still the same behavior.